# i'm getting "Could not find an Android SDK please make sure it is installed" error

Tags: android

You can read about how Calabash-Android is searching for an `Android SDK` and how you can help [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabashandroid/blob/master/documentation/installation.md#prerequisites)

error when trying to run calabash-android commands. i've downloaded `android SDK` and unzipped it.

here is the content of my `.bash_profile`:

```
 export   GEM_HOME=~/.calabash

 export   GEM_PATH=~/.calabash

 export   PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.calabash/bin"

 export   ANDROID_HOME="$PATH:$HOME/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/“
```

Note that I added the `.bash_profile` myself.

Comment: Are you, perchance, trying to run calabash in a terminal or as a task within Android Studio or  IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

u have to type `export ANDROID_HOME=path/to/sdk` inside console. I have same issue in Ubuntu where I have to type it ,ever i restart terminal. Something is wrong with saving Global Variables inside a bash script.

Comment: Sadly, the same thing happens in Mac OS X.

Comment: Maybe saving into ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile will help, but didn't try it ,so up to you if it worked.